# mvvmcross5 navigation service: In what way I should use Initialize method to change UI?

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm playing with mvvmcross5 navigation service.
And I try to change label from Initialize method, but nothing happens.

What I doing wrong?

Here's simple code of it:

```
public class SecondViewModel : MvxViewModel<Dictionary<string, string>>
{
    private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;
    private string _mainPageButtonText = "test";

    public SecondViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }

    public string MainPageButtonText
    {
        get
        {
            return _mainPageButtonText;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _mainPageButtonText, value);
        }
    }

    public IMvxAsyncCommand BackCommand => new MvxAsyncCommand(() => {

        MainPageButtonText = "it works";

        return Task.FromResult(true);
    });

    public override Task Initialize(Dictionary<string, string> parameter)
    {
        MainPageButtonText = "it does not work";

        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in MvvmCross, and will be fixed in 5.0.2. See https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/releases/tag/5.0.2

Comment: it's ok, when are you plan to release 5.0.2?, because I have another issue with dll path in UWP project

Comment: It has been released an hour ago. Also the UWP issue is fixed there.

Comment: I've tested it, and still it doesn't work:( UWP is ok! thanks

Comment: Do you navigate to this viewmodel with the NavigationService?

Comment: Yep, from Main to Second vm, please look at my files https://github.com/JTOne123/XamFormsMvxTemplate/tree/preparations/XamForms.MvxTemplate/XamForms.MvxTemplate.Core/ViewModels

Comment: Hi Martijn, do you have any news about navi?

Comment: Yes, this is fixed in the latest release.

Comment: Are you talking about 5.0.2? It is not working in the version 502 or maybe I doing something wrong